# Can't reload MKMapView while doing other tasks

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, mkmapview

I got my MKMapView running fine on my iOS app. The purpose of the app is to scan a Wifi network for data all the time. Like many times every second. This is just a background task and the user don't need to do anything for that scanning process to work. But, for some reason the MKMapView can't load new tiles at the same time as I'm scanning in the background. I would be lame to show some code from the scanning because I don't even know which part that are interrupting the MapView. So, is this a common problem that have been seen before or is this something weird?

When I move around in the MapView without scanning in background from the Wifi Network the map loads fine and uses both cache and fetches data from the mapping servers.

When I move around in the MapView WHILE scanning in the background no maps are being shown. Just empty boxes that are "telling me that the map are loading".

I'm using this library https://github.com/FuzzyLuke/OBD2Kit to fetch data from an WiFi plug that is connected to a car while I'm trying to show the user's current location on a map.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how you're scanning but *I guess* it is breaking the internet connection and the map view cannot connect to the server then

Comment: I'm using this library https://github.com/FuzzyLuke/OBD2Kit to fetch data from an WiFi plug that is connected to a car while I'm trying to show the user's current location on a map.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "many times every second" - how exactly are you 'scanning' the wifi network for data, and what data is it? Because it sounds like you're creating many dozens, if not more, distinct connections per second, which is going to totally cripple your networking stack, and would explain why your maps can't load.

I would encourage you to share more information about what exactly it is you're doing on the network, because that's almost certainly where the problem is. I can guarantee there's a better way to achieve what you want than firing off tens or hundreds of network requests every second.

Comment: I'm using this library https://github.com/FuzzyLuke/OBD2Kit to fetch data from an WiFi plug that is connected to a car while I'm trying to show the user's current location on a map.